# Need to send response after an action has completed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, web-crawler, imdb

I am trying to make a web crawler which crawls IMDB and lists the movie name and rating. This is my index.js file. 
Suppose i am crawling for 10 movies. I am then saving the crawled results in a different file say 'message.txt'. Now i want to send this message.txt file as a response to any request. But whenever I make a request it always send me an empty file to my browser initially. Then i notice that it takes some time before the crawled results are saved in the message.txt file. I think this is because all actions are asynchronous in nodejs. So is there a way to send the message.txt file only after crawling is complete?

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Running');


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Recieved the get Request');
  var i = 1;
  var count = 0;
  while (count < 10) {
    var url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt' + i + '/'; 
    console.log(url);
    count = count + 1;
    i = i + 1;
    request(url, function(error, response, html) {
      if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var title, ratings, released;
        var json = {
          title: '',
          ratings: '',
          released: ''
        };
        $('.title_wrapper').filter(function() {
          var data = $(this);
          json.title = data.children().first().text().trim();
          json.released = data.children().last().children().last().text().trim();
        });
        $('.ratingValue').filter(function() {
          var data = $(this);
          json.ratings = parseFloat(data.text().trim());
        });
        console.log(json);
        fs.appendFile('message.txt', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4) + '\n', function(err) {});   
      };
    });
  };
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.js');
});
```

Comment: use promises - callback, when the fs stream is done saving the file make a call to send file.

Comment: could you plese explain more @GandalftheWhite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the async package which is great for controlling flow, something like:

```
  console.log('Recieved the get Request');
  var i = 1;
  var count = 0;
  while (count < 10) {
    var url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt' + i + '/';
    console.log(url);
    count = count + 1;
    i = i + 1;
    async.waterfall([
        function sendRequest (callback) {
            if (!error) {
                var $ = cheero.load(html);
                var json = {
                    title: '',
                    ratings: '',
                    released: ''
                }
            }
            $('.title_wrapper').filter(function() {
                var data = $(this);
                json.title = data.children().first().text().trim();
                json.released = data.children().last().children().last().text().trim();
            });
            $('.ratingValue').filter(function() {
                var data = $(this);
                json.ratings = parseFloat(data.text().trim());
            });
            callback(null, JSON.stringify(json, null, 4) + '\n');
        },
        function appendFile (json, callback) {
            fs.appendFile('message.txt', json, function(err) {
                if (err) { callback(err); }
                callback();
            });
        }
    ], function(err) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.js');
    });
```

Comment: Did it using `async` parallel package. Found this link very useful [Execute some function after all asynchronous requests have been called and executed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16866080/3717234)

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.appendFile('message.txt', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4) + '\n', function(err) {
//This part is executed after the process has been completed 
});
```

You have to make a callback there as that part will be only called when your operation has been performed.

We are utilizing the callback feature here although there isn't any concrete callback except the err in our case, we don't need any other badly though.

Please try.

Answer (score 0):

`fs.appendFile()` is asynchronous so the stuff you append to the file won't be there right away when the function returns. So if you want to read send that file to the user, you'll need to do it inside the callback you supply to `fs.appendFile()`.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
...
        fs.appendFile(
          'message.txt',
          JSON.stringify(json, null, 4) + '\n',
          function(err) {
            if (err) {
              // Log the error and send a message to the user here
              return;
            }
            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.js')
          }
        );   
      };
    });
  };
});
```

You may be tempted to use `fs.appendFileSync()` instead. That would be fine for a command line tool, but since this is a web server, do not do that. It will lock up the thread while the I/O happens.

Comment: Each `request()` will return 1 json. Suppose I am calling `request()` 10 times then it might happen after writing once into the message.txt file the `res.sendFile` is fired. So the remaining 9 jsons are not appended. So how to make sure that after all the `request()` calls are made then only the file will sent to the browser